# How to call Azure function when Azure continuous deployment completes a deployment

Tags: git, azure, azure-functions, continuous-deployment, azure-blob-storage

I have following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment) for Azure function continuous deployment. I have successfully setup github Account with Azure function for continuous deployment.

Now I have want to copy Git-hub files to WASB storage. As I have github files in Kudu Console after Azure function continuous deployment, I have an idea to copy git-hub files from D:\home\site\repository to WASB Storage instead of copying files from Github.

I have written Azure function to copy files from D:\home\site\repository to WASB. Now I want to call this Azure function.

How can I call this Azure Function after Azure Function continuous deployment completes a deployment? Because Git-hub files are updated in D:\home\site\repository path once Azure function continuous deployment completed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options to consider.  The simplest is to provide post deployment script/action.  See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks.

Other option is to provide and customize deployment script such that at the end of script so any post operation work you want.   See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments.  In addition, you could consider WebHook; see https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-hooks.

Comment: How can I call Azure function from .cmd file in Post Deployment Action?